# Trigger Observable on Subject's onNext and Share Result

Tags: android, rx-java

I have a button which when pressed should make the `btnSubject`'s `onNext` fire and make an API call in an `Observable` created in my `ViewModel` like so:

```
val apiObservable = 
    btnSubject.flatMap{ apiService.getSomething()
                                  .toResponseOrErrorObservable()
                                  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())}
```

Then I can reuse this observable to create two more, which are then subscribed to from my view allowing me to keep the logic in my `ViewModel` like so:

```
val successObservable = apiObservable.filter{ it.isSuccess() }

val failureObservable = apiObservable.filter{ it.isFailure() }
```

So apiObservable is triggered by the `btnSubject.onNext()` being called.

The view is then updated because it's listening to the `successObservable` and `failureObservable`

Is this possible? Perhaps with a `.share()` on the `apiObservable`?

**UPDATE**

I added the share operator and all observables emitted items when first subscribing. Even the filters didn't stop it... I must be missing something obvious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a few way to do that.

As you have written, using `share()` operator multiplies output to many `Subscribers`. However, you have to be careful, that you also have to call `connect()` to turn cold `Observable` into hot one. If calling also `replay()`, you woudln't need to call `connect()` many times.
([Source](https://medium.com/@p.tournaris/rxjava-one-observable-multiple-subscribers-7bf497646675))

However, there is more simple solution: use Jake Wharton's library [RxReplayingShare](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxReplayingShare). The author of previous blog post suggests it in [his next article](https://medium.com/@p.tournaris/rxjava-rxreplayingshare-emit-only-once-b19acd61b469)

Comment: Thanks for the solution. However, I do not want to replay I only want to listen for the next

Comment: Even though I didn't need reply, I used `publish()` in combination with `connect()`